# How to rotate an image with CSS style transform by an variable of degree?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
console.log("hour"+h+"min"+m+"sec"+s);

document.getElementById("sec").style.transform = "rotate((s*6)deg)";
```

I am trying to rotate an image with ID sec by (current second*6) degree. But it seems css rotate can only take a constant degree like rotate(40deg). 
If I do 
`var x =40; rotate('x'deg);`
or something like that its not going to work.

How do I let it rotate with an variable?

Comment: Try replacing your last statement with, `document.getElementById("sec").style.transform = "rotate(("+s*6+")deg)";`

Comment: Can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is supplying a string of `rotate((s*6)deg)` (literally with the S*6 instead of the result) into the transform style. You need to split the string so that it concatenates the result into the string.

Use this:

```
ar today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
console.log("hour"+h+"min"+m+"sec"+s);

document.getElementById("sec").style.transform = "rotate(" + (s*6) + "deg)";
```

This will pass the value of the variable `s` times 6 into the string. So instead of the CSS parser questioning what the literal string `s*6deg` means, it will instead recieve `120deg` (if the variable `s` were the value 20) which is a valid CSS value. It is the same concept you were using in your `console.log` call one line above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your last statement with,

```
document.getElementById("sec").style.transform = "rotate(("+s*6+")deg)";
```

Since you are passing a string instead of a value for the degree.

Hope this helps.